# How to read CSV where data start stored in one of the columns only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have CSV file like below:

So first row contains all the columns without comma separation and second row has the data in the first column with comma separation

```
COLID                 TEMP1        TEMP2        TEMP3  .....
1,20.1,40.2,8.5
```

how to read and bring it in

```
COLID TEMP1  TEMP2  TEMP3
1      20.1  40.2    8.5
```

dataframe format .

Comment: is the header tab separated or any number of space separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have named file to be read as text.csv.

Important thing is 'sep' argument where we are telling pandas to read csv which is separated by spaces(\s+) or comma or a tab(\t).

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python', sep='\s+|,|\t')
```

**Output**

```
    COLID   TEMP1   TEMP2   TEMP3
0   1       20.1    40.2    8.5
```